# Python selenium how to make python to take the next notepad

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm

I'm making a python script that will automatically post to Instagram. It's a skateboarding niche page and I want to give credit to people I repost... (I'm posting thrue facebook creator studio)

This is how the video picker looks like...

```
skatenr = int(skatenr) + int("1")
    SendKeys = "C://Users/User/PycharmProjects/skateboard auto post/skate/"+str(memenr)+".mp4"
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div/div/div/a/div[2]/input').send_keys(SendKeys)
```

You could see how I got it to take the next post from the folder I store my vids in. My idea was that I store the captions in another folder and name it skate1.txt skate2.txt ...... then like the videos it takes the notepad and puts it in the caption place. How do I make Python pick the next notepad.

```py
def read_line():
    f = open('skate1.txt')
    The = (f.read())
    return The
print(read_line())
```

any ideas?

Regards your friendly guy who started coding yesterday

Answer (score 0):

if you run the code at all time you can use this formular

```
from os import path
x=0
The=[]
while path.exists('skate%s.txt'%str(x)):
    with open("skate%s.txt"%str(x),'r') as file:
       k=file.read()
       The.append(k)
     x+=1
```

now all of your caption will be in the "The" list

Comment: change f to file my mistake sry

Comment: Hey sorry, but something isn't working -  while PATH.exists('skate%s.txt' % str(x)):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'exists'

Comment: use path not PATH. If you still have problem try to use ('skate{}.txt'.format(str(x))) but i think it make no different

Comment: ok I will try to use  ('skate{}.txt'.format(str(x))) bc if I put path (small leters) it says - Unresolved reference 'path'

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time. I think i will just have to give up on this and start with more basic things. Now it keeps showing me - with open('skate{}.txt'.format(str(x)), 'r') as file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'skate11.txt' ..... It showed skate0.txt i added that now it's showing skate11.txt

Comment: try to take your time in reading os libary :https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.split